# Parallel life of DFS shared files?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, dfs, dfs-r

That's a weird one.

We have **3 servers** (Windows Server 2012 R2) with **DFS-N** and **DFS-R** sharing and syncing same folders between themselves. We have those folders mapped on clients as network drives like *x: ("\\contoso.com\Shared")* or *y: ("\\contoso.com\Departments")*. Today one of them users (**Windows 10 Pro** OS) asked me to have a look at a problem: she was placing files into one of subfolders on those drives (and they were there when I was looking it on her PC), but no one else could see them.

So I thought perhaps she was using different DFS server and those are simply not synced between other servers, so I checked every server for contents of mentioned subfolder but none of them had those files.

Next I thought maybe that subfolder was made autonomous by user but when I checked out that feature in Control Panel was actually disabled all the time.

Some more notes:

- User complained that contents of other folders was outdated by few days.
- All file servers contained files which were pretty much synced so she was looking into something different, not into one of the actual servers.
- When I looked mapped drive size on user's computer it was like it was showing actual size of server's disk file system (1.5 Tb used out of 3 Tb) rather disk file share quotes those file shares (600 Gb used out of 745 Gb everyone else were seeing).
- When I remapped network drives again everything went back to normal.

So I'm eager to find out what happened there? How could it be possible that user was working with copy of network drive not present anywhere else with disabled caching?

Comment: When the drive was disconnected and reconnected, did it connect to the same DFS server? It honestly sounds like she was connected to a DFS server with broken DFS-R

Comment: Yeh, I think drive reconnected to the same server. My initial thoughts was of broken DFS-R, but thing is neither of those 3 servers had those files when I looked into folders both by \\srvr\share and by \\srvr\e$.